# Problem with running the app in virtual devices and physical devices

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am not able to make my phone work in the android studio with the latest update. Before it was all good but now its not working. And also same case for the emulators.

Comment: Please give a complete explanation of the scenario. Like which did you update (phone or android studio). What do you mean by not working? What error does it throw?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.